# Dynamically add object to queue inside the worker method

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, threadpool

I am using python multiprocessing Pool and Queue to run tasks in parallel.
But I have to dynamically insert other jobs in the queue and wait for them to finish (they could insert other jobs in the queue too).

```
def add_another(q,blocked_name):
    name = q.get()
    if 'a' in name and name not in blocked_name:
        print('The name contains an a')
        # Here I want to add another name in the queue
        # Like q.put('Another') even if 'Another' will create a loop

if __name__ == '__main__':

    m = Manager()
    q = m.Queue()
    p = Pool(3)

    worker = []

    req = ['alice','amanda','bob','mallery']

    for d in req:
        q.put(d)

    blocked_name = ['mallery','steve']

    for i in range(len(req)):
        worker.append(p.apply_async(add_another, (q,blocked_name,)))

    # Here I want to wait ALL the worker, even the one added inside the add_another method 
    [r.get() for r in worker]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is it your goal to add an additional worker process from inside one of the initial child processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be conflating the content of the Queue and the worker processes — because simply adding a name to the former isn't necessarily going to apply the function to it in a pool worker process.

One way to do what you want is to make use of the optional `callback` function `apply_async()` supports and have it create another worker process from the queue whenever it's been updated. This ensures that one is created for every job added to the queue.

Here's what I'm suggesting. Note I've changed the name of a few variable to make the code more readable.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool


def add_another(queue, blocked_names):
    name = queue.get()
    print(f'processing {name}')
    if 'a' in name and name not in blocked_names:
        print('The name contains an "a"')
        queue.put('Another')  # Add another to queue.
        return True  # Indicate another was added.
    return False  # Indicate another one NOT added.

def check_result(another_added):
    ''' Start processing of another task if one was added to the queue. '''
    if another_added:
        results.append(pool.apply_async(add_another, (queue, blocked_names),
                                        callback=check_result))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    mgr = Manager()
    queue = mgr.Queue()
    pool = Pool(3)

    results = []
    reqs = ['alice', 'amanda', 'bob', 'mallery']
    blocked_names = ['mallery', 'steve']

    # Initialize task queue.
    for req in reqs:
        queue.put(req)

    for _ in range(len(reqs)):
        results.append(pool.apply_async(add_another, (queue, blocked_names),
                                        callback=check_result))

    res = [result.get() for result in results]
#    print(f'{res=}')
    print('-Fini-')
```